# Mongodb: Finding and updating object property from array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection with multiple documents which follow this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "oid" : XXX
    },
    "name" : "Name",
    "videos" [
        {
          "id" : 1,
          "thumbnail" : "thumbnail.jpg",
          "name" : "Name here"
        },
        {
          "id" : 2,
          "thumbnail" : "thumbnail.jpg",
          "name" : "Name here"
        },
        {
          "id" : 3,
          "thumbnail" : "thumbnail.jpg",
          "name" : "Name here"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find and update the a thumbnail of a video, of which I only know the id, but not which document it is in.

This is what I've tried so far, but it's not working properly. All the examples I found relied on knowing the document id, and the array position of the object to update. I also found that doing a query like this found the document okay, but set the whole document as the new thumbnail!

```
db.collection(COLLECTION-NAME, function(err, collection){
    collection.update(
      { 'videos.id' : 2 },
      { $set: { thumbnail: "newThumbnail.jpg" } },
      function(err, result){
        if (!err){
          console.log('saved', result)
        } else {
          console.log('error', err);
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the **[$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)** to update the value of the `thumbnail` field within the embedded document having the `id` of 2:

```
db.collection.update(
   { "videos.id": 2 },
   { "$set": { "videos.$.thumbnail" : "newThumbnail.jpg" } }
)
```